# Final Cut Pro Picture in Picture template

Tags: final-cut-pro-x

I want to try and create a video with one main camera angle that will be used throughout, but on occasions I want to bring up a second camera angle or picture inside the first.

This is all fairly easy to achieve in itself, but I want to make sure that, assuming the dimensions are the same for the secondary picture/video, that it's always in the same place on the screen.  Is there a way to implement a template/anchor point that I can just put these extra pictures/videos into whenever I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have Apple Motion you could make a template which would be easy enough and just drop it on when you need it in the video and then drop the additional image onto the motion template.

OR

(I am going to assume you know how to place 2 layers of video (top one being the PiP one))
the first time you want your PiP get it placed where you want it with all the sizing, placement etc. Then when you want to do it again in the next section just copy and paste the attributes from the first one onto the second one and it should place it in exactly the same place.

Comment: ooo nice how do you copy and paste attributes!?  I havent got apple motion but will look into that too, cheers.

Comment: After you have made all your changes to the clip, select the clip and copy (cmd key + C). Move to the clip you want to paste them to and select it then clip edit > paste attributes ( shift+cmd key+V ). This should make the clip the same as the other one.

Comment: ah cool I'll try that then, cheers! :)